# Checking for disabled button state with Detox

Tags: reactjs, detox

I'm running Detox tests against a React Native ios app. Users need to confirm their passwords to enable Submit button. Is there any way to get Detox to perform a test for a disabled button state? I'm not seeing any matchers on the Detox matchers page that seem to support this functionality, which is coded as a 'disabled' attribute within a JSX statement.

```
       <Button
            small
            title=' Save '
            buttonStyle={[globalStyle.buttons.buttonPrimary, globalStyle.buttons.smallButton]}
            disabled={Object.values(this.state.inCircleObj).length === 0 || this.props.circlePropLoading}
            containerViewStyle={{ marginRight: 20 }}
            onPress={() => { firebase.analytics().logEvent(`${this.constructor.name}_${SAVE_EDIT_CIRCLE}`); this.updateCircle() }}
            fontSize={14} />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check [that thread](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/246#issuecomment-324366092) regarding this issue on detox GitHub.